# How to ignore the TLS certificate on the server

Tags: ssl, https, certificate

If the client can not verify the server's certificate with the rootCA certificate, can the server pass the authentication?

Comment: If the *client* can't verify the server cert/chain, it's the *client's* responsibility to disconnect - not the server's; *a server can't tell/force a client to accept an invalid cert.*

Comment: Also, this is client/implementation-specific, and no client/implementation has been specified.. Even different browsers allow different levels of being able to ignore/bypass misconfigured or expired certs (compare new Chrome versions, which are quite "restrictive" compared to, eg., IE). This bypassing is *by explicit request/operation done by the user*; although some older browser versions still accept questionable certs more readily (and will, usually, display an "security warning" without requiring explicit user action to proceed).

Answer (score 0):

It would be terrible insecure if a server could just instruct a client to ignore any certificate problems. Validation of the server certificate is done by the client to make sure that it actually talks to the expected server and not to some man-in-the-middle attacker. If a server could instruct the client to ignore certificate problems so could a man-in-the-middle attacker do, which means it would be easy to do man in the middle attacks.